# Passing Data to a Route in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, url-routing, node-pdfkit

I'm using a route to create a PDF using PDFKit. I would like to create a PDF that lists all `posts` that belong to the current `calendar`.

This code returns "undefined" for `currentPosts.postDate`. However, if I do something like `currentCalendar.name`, it returns the `calendar` name without issue.

Where did I go wrong?

```
Router.route('/calendars/:_id/getPDF', function() {
     var currentCalendar = Calendars.findOne(this.params._id);
     var currentPosts = Posts.find({}, {fields: {calendarId: this.params._id}});
     var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
     doc.fontSize(12);
     doc.text(currentPosts.postDate, 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
     this.response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
         'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
     });
     this.response.end( doc.outputSync() );
 }, {where: 'server'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this, but this caught my eye:

```
var currentPosts = Posts.find({}, {fields: {calendarId: this.params._id}});
```

`Posts.find({})` will return a whole recordset. But then you reference `currentPosts.postDate` as if it's one item. Maybe try this:

```
var currentPost = Post.findOne({_id: this.params._id}, {fields: {postDate: 1}});
[...]
doc.text(currentPost.postDate, 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
```

If you wanted to get all the post dates, you'd have to loop through the results:

```
// .fetch() turns a mongo cursor into an array of objects
var currentPosts = Posts.find({calendarId: this.params._id}).fetch();

// Assuming you're using underscore.js
_.each(currentPosts, function (o) {
  // do something with o.postDate
});
```

Comment: I was hoping currentPost.postDate would list all of the posts post dates. Each calendar has multiple poss.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified no where, and restricted the fields that come back.

The fields node in the options parameter lets you defined whether or not to include fields or not: That should actually be in your where object.

You probably want your currentPosts to be structure like so

```
var where = {calendarId: this.params._id};
var options = {fields: {postDate: 1}}; // Specify the fields your actually using
var currentPosts = Posts.find(where, options);
```